# Adding Rect to canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I'm trying to add a [Rect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx)-object to a Canvas. Using a Rectangle object, it's easy to .Add it to the Canvas. It doesn't seem so simple for Rect. On the provided link, I've found the following code to achieve what I want:

```
Path myPath1 = new Path();
myPath1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath1.StrokeThickness = 1;
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 204, 255);
myPath1.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

Rect myRect1 = new Rect();
myRect1.X = 10;
myRect1.Y = 100;
myRect1.Width = 150;
myRect1.Height = 100;
RectangleGeometry myRectangleGeometry1 = new RectangleGeometry();
myRectangleGeometry1.Rect = myRect1;

GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup1 = new GeometryGroup();
myGeometryGroup1.Children.Add(myRectangleGeometry1);

myPath1.Data = myGeometryGroup1;

// Add path shape to the UI.
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
myCanvas.Children.Add(myPath1);
this.Content = myCanvas;
```

I can't believe I have to go through all this just to add a simple Rect-object! And when I want to alter a Rect (for example by dragging), I have to go through this all again? There must be an easier way. What should I do?

EDIT: I don't use the [System.Windows.Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object because I can't calculate if a certain Point (OnClick) is there. [System.Drawing.Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can do that but it's asking for a Rectangle instead of a Point, even though the documentation says otherwise... Also, you cannot set the `Opacity` or `Stroke` attributes for example on that Rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out if a `Rectangle` is clicked, you would either add a `MouseDown` or `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler to the Rectangle object itself:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="100" Height="100"
               Fill="AliceBlue" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
</Canvas>

private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = sender as Rectangle;
    // do something
}
```

or call [`InputHitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) on the Canvas and cast the returned object to `Rectangle`.

```
<Canvas MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="100" Height="100"
               Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
</Canvas>

private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = sender as UIElement;
    var rect = parent.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(parent)) as Rectangle;
    if (rect != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And of course you can set properties like `Opacity` or `Stroke` on a [System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx)
.

Comment: Scratch my last comment, I'm gonna try it out immediately!